# Get all images from specific Facebook album with Graph API PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi I'm trying to grab all pictures from a specific album (always the same hardcoded id).
I'm using the Graph API PHP SDK from Facebook. This is my code:

```
<?php
require 'phpfiles/facebook.php';

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'aaaa',
    'secret' => 'bbbb',
    'cookie' => true
));

$user_profile = $facebook->api('/1881235503185/photos?access_token=cccc');
var_dump($user_profile);
```

The var_dump output:

```
array(1) { ["data"]=> array(0) { } }
```

- 1881235503185 is the id of MY album that is not restricted, it's open to everybody
- the access_token is the token I get from my application page for my fb id. I don't get oauth errors.
- I have the permissions (user_photos) and tryed to add a dozen of other permissions.
- When I try it with the Graph API Explorer it works to.

When I use the Javascript SDK it works fine...

```
FB.api('/1881235503185/photos?access_token=cccc', function(response) {
    alert(response.data[0].name);
});
```

Output: Diep in de put

Am I forgetting something?

Comment: Does that js version really work for you? I need to do something exactly the same and face a problem with JS solution. When I try to call this while being logged in as the owner of the album - that works. However when I log in as any other user the response is empty, despite the fact that the album is public and there are public photos in it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got it! It should be:

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/1881235503185/photos', array('access_token' => 'cccc'));
```

With the new Facebook PHP SDK it should be:

```
$albumjson = $facebook->api('/1881235503185?fields=photos');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
    require_once 'library/facebook.php';
    try{
        $facebook = new Facebook(array(
                'appId' => $app_id,
                'secret' => $app_secret,
                'cookie' => true
        ));
        if(is_null($facebook->getUser()))
        {
                header("Location:{$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('req_perms' => 'user_status,publish_stream,user_photos'))}");
                exit;
        }
        $me = $facebook->api('/me');
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
        echo '<p>Please try clearing your browser cookies or <a href="http://demos.frnzzz.com/fbAlbum/photos.php">click here</a>.</p>';
        die;
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.latest.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.slideshow').cycle({
                fx: 'fade'
            });
        });
        </script> 
        <title>WebSPeaks.in | Access facebook Albums on your site using PHP</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php
    $albums = $facebook->api('/me/albums');

    $action = $_REQUEST['action'];

    $album_id = '';
    if(isset($action) && $action=='viewalbum'){ 
        $album_id = $_REQUEST['album_id'];
        $photos = $facebook->api("/{$album_id}/photos");
        ?>
        <div class="slideshow"> 
        <?php
        foreach($photos['data'] as $photo)
        {
            echo "<img src='{$photo['source']}' />";
        }
        ?>
        </div>
        <?php
    }

    $pageURL .= 'http://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    echo '<div class="alb">';
    if(strstr($pageURL,'.php?')){
        $and = '&';
    }else{
        $and = '?';
    }

    echo '<p class="hd">My Albums</p>';
    foreach($albums['data'] as $album)
    {
        if($album_id == $album['id']){
            $name = '<b><u>'.$album['name'].'</u></b>';
        }else{
            $name = $album['name'];
        }
        echo '<p>'."<a href=".$pageURL.$and."action=viewalbum&album_id=".$album['id'].">".$name.'</a></p>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I used you example and it automatically redirect to facebook.com, any solution to that?

Comment: Are you sure this line is working? $photos = $facebook->api("/{$album_id}/photos");

Answer (score 2):

I find it strange that it works with JS and not PHP... Makes me think it's something to do with your PHP FB setup..  Have you tried another call to check it's not? Such as

```
$facebook->api('/me');
```

Also make sure you have checked these:

> To read the 'photo' object you need
>
> any valid access_token if it is public user_photos permission to
>   access photos and albums uploaded by the user user_photo_video_tags
>   permission to access photos in which the user has been tagged
>   friends_photos permission to access friends' photos
>   friends_photo_video_tags permission to access photos in which the
>   user's friends have been tagged

Src:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

Comment: I have tried all those permissions, no success.
api('/me') gives an oauth error (!?)
but when I use api('/[my_uid]') I get all my info... Also tried to downgrade from 3.0.1 to 3.0.0 also ni success...

Comment: I got it! It should be: $user_profile = $facebook->api('/1881235503185/photos', array('access_token' => 'cccc'));