# How to get user all photos from facebook

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am developing a website and i want to give an option to the user they can select the photos from facebook,it should not only profile pics,it must contain all the photos present in user facebook photos or in album,i have found many answer on internet they have solved my problem,so kindly give me your suggestion to solve my requirement

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have already read it, but I hope it can help you:

[Get all images from specific Facebook album with Graph API PHP SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678756/get-all-images-from-specific-facebook-album-with-graph-api-php-sdk)

Comment: after using the code suggested by you i am only getting the text on my page is my album and i am not getting the photos from facebook