# How to get all the photos from facebook for the user

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am working on a website from which user can edit their photo,and i also want to give an option to the user i.e user can select all the photos from facebook it should not only profile pics it may be from the photos and it may be from their album.I have searched a lot on internet but unfortunately no one has worked for me,please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

First You need to read http://developers.facebook.com/
Also you can google for tutorials here is one:

http://steve.veerman.ca/2012/facebook-api-fql-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply,but i am not getting the exact result that i need please suggest me the code according to my requirement so that i will be able to get the exact result

Comment: Suggest you the code???? Write your own  and get back to StackOverflow with you code snippets and we will help with suggestions///

Comment: I am using the last code of this url i am only getting the text my album and not the images that i need. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678756/get-all-images-from-specific-facebook-album-with-graph-api-php-sdk